# Python-eve: Combine role based and user-restricted access?

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, eve

I have a fairly simple use case but can't figure out how to stitch it together.

Basically I want to use user-restricted access for regular users, i.e. they can upload files via an API and other users cannot touch those files via the API.

At the same time I want a special user (admin/super-user) to be able to use the API to GET e.g. all files for a specific user.

Does anybody have any pointers to examples of this or can help point me in the right direction to do this?

One idea I thought of was to pass an additional (optional) parameter to check_auth containing the _id of the user that the admin wants to look at, so if the admin passes in that parameter it will override the admins own _id. Would this work or does check_auth have a set parameter list? any security issues with this approach?

Or is there a better approach - a separate API instance perhaps that uses the same mongoDB collections (is that even possible?).

Regards,
Anton

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?